Is the cut-down of a positive invertible element postive and invertible?
Let $\mathfrak A$ be a unital C*-algebra; let $A \in \mathfrak A$ be such that $\sigma_{\mathfrak A}(A) \subset [a,\infty)$ for some $a > 0$; let $p \in \mathfrak A$ be a (self-adjoint) projection.
Is $pAp$ positive and invertible in $p \mathfrak A p$? In other words, is $\sigma_{p\mathfrak A p}(pAp) \subset [a',\infty)$ for some $a' > 0$?

If $A$ is selfadjoint, the answer is yes, and $a'=a$: you have $A\geq aI$, so
$$
pAp\geq p(aI)p=ap.
$$
If you allow $A$ to not be selfadjoint, then the answer is no in general. Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-3\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad p=\frac12\,\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} . 
$$
Then $\sigma(A)=\{1\}$, while
$$
pAp=\frac14\,\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\-1&-1 \end{bmatrix} =-\frac12\,p
$$
so $\sigma_{p\mathcal A p}(pAp)=\{-\frac12\}.$

$\def\A{\mathfrak A}$
Edit: $pAp\geq0$ on $\A$ if and only if $pAp\geq0$ on $p\A p$.
Here are two ways to check this. If you think of $\A\subset B(H)$, then
$$
\langle pAp\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle Ap\xi,p\xi\rangle\geq0. 
$$
If you want to think of the spectrum, if $pAp-\lambda p$ is invertible on $\A$, there exists $B$ such that $B(pAp-\lambda p)=(pAp-\lambda p)B=1$. Then
$$
(pBp)(pAp-\lambda p)=p\,B(pAp-\lambda p)=p\,1=p, 
$$
and similarly on the right. So $pAp-\lambda p$ is invertible on $p\A p$, showing that $\sigma_{p\A p}(pAp)\subset \sigma_\A(pAp)$. And, then if $\lambda\ne0$ and $pAp-\lambda p$ is invertible on $p\A p$, there exists $B\in p\A p$ with $$B(pAp-\lambda p)=(pAp-\lambda p)B=p.$$ Then, as $B=pBp$,
$$
\big(B+\frac1\lambda(1-p)\big)(pAp-\lambda 1)=B(pAp-\lambda P)+1-p=p+1-p=1. 
$$
If follows that
$$
\sigma_{p\A p}(pAp)\cup\{0\}= \sigma_\A(pAp)
$$

Assuming $A$ is self-adjoint: $pAp - ap \geq 0$ \emph{in $\mathfrak A$}; why does this imply $pAp - ap \geq 0$ \emph{in $p \mathfrak Ap$}?

From my calculation, it turns out that $\sigma_{p\mathfrak A p}(pBp) \subseteq \sigma_{\mathfrak A}(pBp)$ for any $B \in \mathfrak A$. The result would then follow. But is this obvious?

Too long for a comment, I edited details into the answer.
